# is it possible to keep the checked values of radio button should be same when we move from current page to previous page in php?

Tags: php

is it possible to keep the checked values of radio buttons  should be same as we selected before when we move from current page to previous page in php?
please explain with sample code....

my dynamically generated radio button values are posted automatically when am going to next page in pagination before i submit the button.
i have 20 questions and answers per page.i need to evaluate them.i got answers in a array.
i cant get users selected radio button values while moving next or previous buttons with pagination,please help any one.
thanks in advance

Comment: use `$_SESSION['var_name']`

Comment: you have to establish your navigation so that when the browser back button is pressed the page is rendered again from the server.

Comment: There is something called [`sessions`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to keep selected radio button values to next page in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180601/how-to-keep-selected-radio-button-values-to-next-page-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

### You can do this with JavaScript or jQuery...

**HTML**

One of my favorite ways to do a multi-page form, if your pagination doesn't need to create new (copy/pasteable) links, is to have pagination controls which invoke JavaScript to show & hide sections, like this:

```
<div id='section1' class='section'> ... BUNCH OF RADIOS ... </div>
<div id='section2' class='section'> ... BUNCH OF RADIOS ... </div>

<div id='links' style='display:none;'>
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='show' data-section='1'>1</a> | 
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='show' data-section='2'>2</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

Then, create some JavaScript functions (I'm assuming you have jQuery installed, if you don't, you can do this with pure Javascript but it's not as pretty):

```
function hideAllSections() {
    $('.section').hide(0);
}

function showSection(section) {
    $('#section' + section).show(0);
}

$('.show').click(function(){
    showSection($(this).data('section'));
});
```

Finally, to hide all the sections except the first as soon as the document loads:

```
$(function(){
    hideAllSections();
    showSection(1);
    $('#links').show(0);
});
```

**Why do it this way?**

There are a few reasons I like this method:

1. It's progressive enhancement. If the user doesn't have JavaScript, the form will simply all display on 1 page.
2. You only have to do one submit function, as all the inputs are technically on one HTML page, they just appear on separate pages because of the jQuery pagination.

The only con I can think of is that a user would have to complete it in one sitting.

Answer (score 0):

This could help you start

**HTML**

```
<input name="answers[0]"  class="button-choice" type="radio" value="1"/>
<input name="answers[1]"  class="button-choice" type="radio" value="1"/>
.
.
.
```

**Server side**

```
$answers = unserialize($_SESSION['answers']); // to retrieve user selection
$answers = array_merge($answers,  $_POST['answers']); // merges posted values with the ones already kept in session
$_SESSION['answers'] = serialize($answers); // to keep user selections
```